# Rcpp not compiling with Intel MIC

Tags: r, intel, rcpp

I am trying to make this minimal Rcpp/Intel pragma code to work, however running into some pretty big errors which I am struggling to overcome.

**Code**

This is the full code that I am trying to run - it is a simple text read out showing if the target Xeon Phi device is engaged as per this website: [Offload Computations from Servers with an Intel® Xeon Phi™ Processor](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/how-to-use-offload-over-fabric-with-knights-landing-intel-xeon-phi-processor), and this is based on a sample code found here: [Lightning-Fast R Machine Learning Algorithms](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1151606/Lightning-Fast-R-Machine-Learning-Algorithms):

```
library(Rcpp)
library(inline)
# Create and register a Rcpp plugin
plug <- Rcpp:::Rcpp.plugin.maker(
  include.before = "#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>"
)
registerPlugin("daalNB", plug)

whatCPU <- 
'
#pragma omp declare target
void what_cpu()
{
  uint32_t eax;
  const uint32_t xeon_phi_x100_id = 0x00010;
  const uint32_t xeon_phi_x200_id = 0x50070;

  __asm volatile("cpuid":"=a"(eax):"a"(1));

  uint32_t this_cpu_id =  eax & 0xF00F0;

  if (this_cpu_id == xeon_phi_x100_id)
    printf("This CPU is Intel(R) XeonPhi(TM) x100 Processor!");
  else
    if (this_cpu_id == xeon_phi_x200_id)
      printf("This CPU is Intel(R) XeonPhi(TM) x200 Processor!");
    else
      printf("This CPU is other Intel(R) Processor.");
}
'

offloadExampleRcpp <- 
'
//[[Rcpp::plugins(openmp)]]
  printf("Running on host: ");
  what_cpu();

#pragma offload target(mic:0)
{
  printf("Running on target: ");
  what_cpu();
}
'

runOffloadExample <- cxxfunction(sig = signature(), body = offloadExampleRcpp, plugin="daalNB", includes = '
//[[Rcpp::plugins(openmp)]]
#pragma omp declare target
void what_cpu()
{
  uint32_t eax;
  const uint32_t xeon_phi_x100_id = 0x225d;
  const uint32_t xeon_phi_x200_id = 0x50070;

  __asm volatile("cpuid":"=a"(eax):"a"(1));

  uint32_t this_cpu_id =  eax & 0xF00F0;

  if (this_cpu_id == xeon_phi_x100_id)
    printf("This CPU is Intel(R) XeonPhi(TM) x100 Processor!");
  else
    if (this_cpu_id == xeon_phi_x200_id)
      printf("This CPU is Intel(R) XeonPhi(TM) x200 Processor!");
    else
      printf("This CPU is other Intel(R) Processor.");

}
', verbose = 2)

runOffloadExample()
```

**What I have tried and Errors:**

I have set up the software stack the the Xeon Phi properly, and this can be confirmed by when I compile the .c code (that is wrapped inside Rcpp in the above code) outside of R, using the Intel icc compiler, it is successful; namely I am able to get the exact output as show in the [Intel website](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/how-to-use-offload-over-fabric-with-knights-landing-intel-xeon-phi-processor)  processor.

It seems however, that when the same .c code is wrapped inside Rcpp, the following errors arise which prevent compilation (this a sample from a much longer readout):

```
Compilation argument:
 /usr/local/lib64/R/bin/R CMD SHLIB file306737f15222.cpp 2> file306737f15222.cpp.err.txt 
/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2017.1.132/linux/bin/intel64/icc -I/usr/local/lib64/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I"/home/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include" -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -qopenmp -c file306737f15222.cpp -o file306737f15222.o
file306737f15222.cpp(52): warning #2571: variable has not been declared with compatible "target" attribute
  BEGIN_RCPP
  ^

file306737f15222.cpp(63): warning #2570: function has not been declared with compatible "target" attribute
  END_RCPP
  ^

file306737f15222.cpp(63): warning #2570: function has not been declared with compatible "target" attribute
  END_RCPP
  ^
```

**Furthermore**, the above error readout is followed by tonnes and tonnes of the below errors (again, I have only included a sample for the sake of brevity, however I believe that the other errors are all related to the same issue as posed in my question):

```
/home/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/protection/Shelter.h(34): warning #2570: function has not been declared with compatible "target" attribute
              Rcpp_unprotect(nprotected) ;
              ^
          detected during:
            instantiation of "Rcpp::Shelter<T>::~Shelter() [with T=SEXP]" at line 323 of "/home/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/exceptions.h"
            instantiation of "SEXP exception_to_condition_template(const Exception &, bool) [with Exception=Rcpp::exception]" at line 339 of "/home/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/exceptions.h"

/home/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/protection/Shelter.h(30): warning #2570: function has not been declared with compatible "target" attribute
              return Rcpp_protect(x) ;
                     ^
          detected during:
            instantiation of "SEXP Rcpp::Shelter<T>::operator()(SEXP) [with T=SEXP]" at line 326 of "/home/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/exceptions.h"
            instantiation of "SEXP exception_to_condition_template(const Exception &, bool) [with Exception=Rcpp::exception]" at line 339 of "/home/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/exceptions.h"

/home/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/utils/tinyformat/tinyformat.h(218): warning #2570: function has not been declared with compatible "target" attribute
      static void invoke(std::ostream& /*out*/, const T& /*value*/) { TINYFORMAT_ASSERT(0); }
                                                                      ^
          detected during:
            instantiation of "void tinyformat::detail::formatValueAsType<T, fmtT, convertible>::invoke(std::ostream &, const T &) [with T=const char *, fmtT=char, convertible=false]" at line 329
            instantiation of "void tinyformat::formatValue(std::ostream &, const char *, const char *, int, const T &) [with T=const char *]" at line 528
            instantiation of "void tinyformat::detail::FormatArg::formatImpl<T>(std::ostream &, const char *, const char *, int, const void *) [with T=const char *]" at line 504
            instantiation of "tinyformat::detail::FormatArg::FormatArg(const T &) [with T=const char *]" at line 881
            instantiation of "tinyformat::detail::FormatListN<N>::FormatListN(const Args &...) [with N=1, Args=<const char *>]" at line 930
            instantiation of "tinyformat::detail::FormatListN<<expression>> tinyformat::makeFormatList(const Args &...) [with Args=<const char *>]" at line 966
            instantiation of "void tinyformat::format(std::ostream &, const char *, const Args &...) [with Args=<const char *>]" at line 975
            instantiation of "std::string tinyformat::format(const char *, const Args &...) [with Args=<const char *>]" at line 226 of "/home/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/exceptions.h"
            instantiation of "Rcpp::not_compatible::not_compatible(const char *, Args &&...) [with Args=<const char *const &>]" at line 37 of "/home/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/r_cast.h"
```

Wondering if anyone can help point me to what issues are resulting in the above errors? I recognise that I might be missing something fundamental owing to my in familiarity with C and the Rcpp package and so please excuse this.

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: Are there any errors besides the warnings you are quoting? If not, does the resulting function work? Two suggestions: Use Rcpp attributes instead of the inline package. Use the offload pragma only in a function that is called by the function exposed to R.